# How to save array into Object in Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I'm trying to save an array data(from CarteData object) into CustomerData object in realm but I got the error from the line of append data to Object. I'm just  new with Swift, please tell me the right way of storing data array to object. Thanks so much.

```
let carte = CarteData()
carte.carteID = record.value(forKey: "carteID") as! String
carte.carteMemo = record.value(forKey: "carteMemo") as! String
newCustomer.cartes.append(carte)
```

[image]

**Error crash message:**

[image]

**My CustomerData Object:**

```
class CustomerData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var cusName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cusID: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cusMail: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var cusBirth: Date?
    let cartes = List<CarteData>()
}
```

[image]

**My CarteData Object:**

```
class CarteData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var carteID: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var carteMemo: String = ""
    var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: CustomerData.self, property: "cartes")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show code as text and not screenshot of the code so that it becomes easier for others to copy, paste and test your code in their systems.

Comment: thank u, i have edited the post

Comment: As the exception states, you're using accessing a `Realm` (or an object retrieved from it) from a thread other than the thread it was created on. Breaking on the point the exception is raised will reveal which line of code is responsible. You should then be able to tell from inspecting your code which object is being accessed from a thread other than the one it was created on.

Comment: One thing sticks out at me: you appear to create `newCustomer`, add it to the Realm, then later mutate it within a CloudKit fetch completion block. It's very likely that the callback is performed on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're so right. It will happen in a different thread so what I have to do is let the cloudkit fetching happen on the same thread. But i'm just new and don't know how to fetch cloudkit reference in same thread (could you please show me the way - i really thank you so much)